# Simple Clone array function not working

Tags: javascript

```js
function cloneArray(array) {
  var l = array.length;
  var copy = new Array();
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    copy[i] = array[i];
  }
  console.log(copy);
}
return;

cloneArray([2, 3, 5]);
```

Thank you for your help, 
It doesn't give me an error,  but it won't log anything on the console...

Comment: Why do you have a `return` statement outside your function?

Comment: Thank you! That was it,  can't make an error with these programming languages lol

Comment: horrible syntax produce inattentiveness error

Answer (score 1):

Cloning an array is as easy as `.slice(0)`.

```
function cloneArray(arr){
  return arr.slice(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna check that method